# Spring Data Redis Repository support does not read back embedded complex objects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I have a spring-boot application (1.4RC1, I know it's RC, but Spring Data Redis 1.7.2 is not) where I'm using spring-boot-starter-redis.

The application uses a Spring Data Repository (`CrudRepository`) which should save an object (using `@RedisHash` annotation) with `String` and `Boolean` properties and one custom class property, which also has only `Strings` and `Longs` as properties.

When I save an object (via the repository), everything went fine and I can see all the properties in the database as I would expect.
When I want to read the data from the database (via the repository) I only get the properties from the parent object. The custom class property is null.

I would expect to get the property loaded from the database as well. As the documentation states you can write a [custom converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis.repositories.mapping), but since I don't need to do that, when I want to write the data, I shouldn't need to write a reading converter as well.

I wonder if I need to annotate the custom class property, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation. Can you point me in the right direction?

The classes are as follows:

Class sample:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"isActive", "sampleCreated", "sampleConfiguration"})
@RedisHash
public class Sample {

    @Id
    private String sampleIdentifier;

    private Boolean isActive;

    private Date sampleCreated;

    private SampleConfiguration sampleConfiguration;

    public Sample(String sampleIdentifier, SampleConfiguration sampleConfiguration){
        this.sampleIdentifier = sampleIdentifier;
        this.sampleConfiguration = sampleConfiguration;
    }

}
```

Class SampleConfiguration:

```
@Data
public class SampleConfiguration {

    private String surveyURL;

    private Long blockingTime;

    private String invitationTitle;

    private String invitationText;

    private String participateButtonText;

    private String doNotParticipateButtonText;

    private String optOutButtonText;

    private Long frequencyCappingThreshold;

    private Long optOutBlockingTime;

}
```

Comment: Show us your entity class.

Comment: have you had a look at the [examples project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/redis/repositories). The embedded object `Address` is read back correctly in this [test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/redis/repositories/src/test/java/example/springdata/redis/repositories/PersonRepositoryTests.java#L169). Would you mind adding a default constructor to you entity just to check if that might be the cause, and potentially open an issue in [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added `@NoArgsConstructor` to my `Sample` class as Christoph Strobl suggested. Then the repository reads the `SampleConfiguration` correctly. Thanks, Christoph!

Comment: I created [DATAREDIS-544](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-544) to tackle that issue.